# Web scraping reviews from Amazon only returns data for the first page

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to scrape reviews from Amazon. The reviews can appear on multiple pages to scrape more than one page I construct a list of links which I later scrape separately:

```
# Construct list of links to scrape multiple pages
links = []
for x in range(1,5):
    links.append(f'https://www.amazon.de/-/en/SanDisk-microSDHC-memory-adapter-performance/product-reviews/B08GY9NYRM/ref=cm_cr_dp_d_show_all_btm?ie=UTF8&reviewerType=all_reviews&pageNumber={x}')
```

I then use requests and beautiful soup to obtain the raw review data as below:

```
# Scrape all links in the constructed list
reviews = []
for link in links:
    html = requests.get(link, headers=HEADERS)
    if html.status_code == 200:
        # HTML response was sucssesfull
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html.parser')
        results = soup.find_all('span', {'data-hook': 'review-body'})
        print(len(results))
        for review in results:
            reviews.append(review.text.replace('\n', ''))
    else:
        # HTML response was unsuccsessfull
        print('[BAD HTML RESPONSE] Response Code =', html.status_code)
```

Each page contains 10 Reviews and I receive all 10 reviews for the first page (&pageNumber=1), in each following page I do not receive any information.

[Output of above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kkyD.png)

When checking the corresponding soup objects I cant find the review information. Why is this?

I tried only scraping page 2 outside of the for loop but no review information is returned.

Two months ago I tried the same code which worked on over 80 pages. I do not understand why it is not working now (has Amazon changed something?) Thanks for your time and help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I happened to come across the same exact problem as you. Did abit of research, turns out you would need to give proper headers (not just the user-agent). I'm not sure what header you used but this works for me:

go to http://httpbin.org/get
Copy everything under "headers", but remove "Host", and paste it as your header!

Hopefully, this works for you!

Comment: Please take a minute to read - > https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer and provide the and context as text. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The reason why `soup` doesn't contain any review information is because Amazon is returning a page with a CAPTCHA rather than the actual page with the product reviews.
You can verify this by dumping the returned HTML into a file and opening it in your browser:

```
with open("example.html") as f:
  f.write(str(soup))
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to prevent the page from returning a CAPTCHA. Or a different way of getting the Review information?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem by giving the correct headers.

```
header = { 
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7", 
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br", 
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9", 
    "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1", 
    "Referer": "https://www.google.com/",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
}
```

try using this header

Read this blog, if you want to know more about headers. 
https://www.zenrows.com/blog/web-scraping-headers#what-are-http-headers

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/997587

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34544600)